# Naive Bayes method for two dice

Tags: python, naivebayes

I need a help with realization of naïve Bayes method for two dice - one of them is a 'normal' die with six sides such that each of the sides comes up with equal probability of `1/6`. The other one is a loaded die that gives the outcome `6` with every second try.

My program should get as its input the choice of the die and then simulates a sequence of ten rolls.

I have to start from the odds `1:1`, and then apply the Naive Bayes method to update the odds after each outcome to decide which of the dice was chose (most likely). It should return `True` if the most likely die is the loaded one, and `False` otherwise.

My code:

```
import numpy as np

p1 = [1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6]   # normal
p2 = [1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/2]   # loaded

def roll(loaded):
    if loaded:
        print("a loaded die")
        p = p2
    else:
        print("a normal die")
        p = p1

    # roll the dice 10 times
    sequence = np.random.choice(6, size=10, p=p) + 1 
    for roll in sequence:
        print("rolled %d" % roll)
        
    return sequence

def bayes(sequence):
    odds = 1.0           # start with odds 1:1
    for roll in sequence:
        for i in range(len(p1)):
            r = p1[i]/p2[i]
        if r == 10/6:
            odds = 1.0*(10/6)**roll
        elif r == 1/3:
            odds = 1.0*(1/3)**roll
    if odds > 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

sequence = roll(True)
if bayes(sequence):
    print("More likely loaded")
else:
    print("More likely normal")
```

The idea was to distinguish between the case of 0.1 and 0.5 probabilities for the loaded dice, but unfortunately the code doesn't properly work. Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if r == 10/6:
    odds = 1.0*(10/6)**roll
elif r == 1/3:
    odds = 1.0*(1/3)**roll
```

Did you consider the possibility that neither of these is the case? Let's examine it directly:

```
>>> ((1/6) / (1/10)) == 10/6
False
```

Huh. It turns out you [can't expect floating-point numbers to do that](https://0.30000000000000004.com/).

But there is no reason to perform this conditional check anyway, because *you want to do fundamentally the same thing regardless of the value of r*.

Simply:

```
odds = 1.0 * r**roll
```

Separately, you don't need Numpy for this (check out [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.choices)). There's also [a `Fraction` type provided in the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html).

Comment: Do you mean this? 

for i in range(len(p1)):
            r = p1[i]/p2[i]
            if r == 10/6:
                odds = 1.0*r**(roll)
            elif r == 1/3:
                odds = 1.0*r**(roll).
Still doesn't work.

Comment: What part of "there is no reason to perform this conditional check anyway" was unclear? Your code for this **should not have** `if` or `elif` in it, because your code **does not care** about the specific value of `r`. The error occurs because you are expecting an exact comparison to work with floating-point numbers, and floating-point numbers **do not work that way**, as I already explicitly told you, and gave a link to explain. I cannot help you if you do not **read**.

Comment: I tried various cases, but it still doesn't pass the test (unfortunately, but there might be bugs). Will try to fix it. Thanks a lot, anyway! PS. I read what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Given 10 rolls of a die, if the die is fair, the probability that you'll get that exact sequence of rolls is `(1/6)**10`

Given 10 rolls of your loaded die, the probability that you'll get that exact sequence of rolls is `(1/10)**(number of non-sixes) * (1/2) ** (number of sixes)`

Notice that these two values are just

```
math.product(p1[i - 1] for i in sequence)
math.product(p2[i - 1] for i in sequence)
```

Given that the a priori probability of the two dice is 1:1, you can just compare these two probabilities and pick the biggest.

Comment: I tried this: 
for i in range(len(p1)):
            odds = math.prod(p1[i - 1] for i in sequence)
        for i in range(len(p2)):
            odds = math.prod(p2[i - 1] for i in sequence).
And it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm confused.  You have a double loop.  Why are you doing this?  You don't need the outer `for i in range(len(p1))` if you also have `(.... for i in sequence)`.

Comment: In what way didn't it work for you.  I just tried some tests, and it made the correct determination 87 out of 100 tests

Comment: I tried with two for loops to distinguish between odds. Well, the test gives error smth like True != False or False != True.

Comment: You're not going to get 100%.  A random die can look loaded, and a loaded die can look random.  I was able to guess right 90% of the time.

Comment: I tried various cases, but it still doesn't pass the test (there might be bugs). Will try to fix it soon. Thank you!

Comment: I should also add.  Suppose the two math.products above are `a` and `b`.  Then the probability is `a/(a + b)` that it's a fair die, and `b/(a + b)` that it's cooked.  That's where the Bayesian comes in.  You are never 100% certain.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future, after struggling with this myself quite some time I found out the both the OP and myself did a stupid mistake of not rounding the probabilities with parentheses. The "for i in range..." part is not needed in this problem but the important part is to put p1[i] and p2[i] inside parentheses since their values can be 1/6 and 1/10, and when you write r = 1/10/1/6 it equals to 0.0166... and not the actual value we want (when the roll is not 6): r = (1/10) / (1/6) = 0.6